# Codeigniter - Form validation not showing error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to validate one of my `input` fields, but it seems not working on mine. I trying to put the errors using `session->flashdata` and `redirect` to the `my_view.php` page to send the `session`

here is my code:

**my_view.php**

```
<body>
<?php
    $field_error = $this->session->flashdata('fields');
?>
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>

<input type="text" name="login[name]" class="fname" placeholder="First">
 <?php if (isset($field_error['login[name]'])) { ?>
                                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $field_error['login[name]']; ?></span>
                            <?php } ?>
<br>

<button id="send">Save</button>
</body>
```

**my_controller.php**

```
       public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('my_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('my_view');
}        

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('login[name]', 'First Name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){    
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('fields', $this->form_validation->error_array());


                    redirect(site_url('my_controller'));

                    exit();
                }
```

Comment: replace `redirect()` with `$this->load->view('');`

Answer (score 0):

Load your target view, something like this:

```
$this->load->view('any_directory/view_name');
```

Or

```
$this->load->view('my_view');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using redirect(),flashdata will be refreshed. You may use `$this->load->view('my_view');`
Or the method described bellow :

Do this in your controller's validation : `in your if condition.`

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('login[name]', 'First Name', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {          
            $this->load->view('my_view'); //removing your flashdata,codeigniter provides it's validation method to show errors in your view.
        }
```

and in your **view**,

```
<body>
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>

<input type="text" name="login[name]" class="fname" placeholder="First">
 <?= validation_errors(); ?>
<br>

<button id="send">Save</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not discussing your implementation as such, your Main Issue is your form code needs to be wrapped in `<form> </form>` or using the form helper `<?php echo form_open(); ?>`

```
<body>
<?php $field_error = $this->session->flashdata('fields');
?>
<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="login[name]" class="fname" placeholder="First">
    <?php if (isset($field_error['login[name]'])) { ?>
        <span class="help-block"><?php echo $field_error['login[name]']; ?></span>
    <?php } ?>
    <br>
    <button id="send">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
```

You can discover this kind of thing by performing `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on things like `$this->input->post()` and `$this->session->flashdata()`; So you can actually see what is happening...

In cases like this, you need to be able to debug using something like the above...

Comment: actually I'm submitting the data using ajax.

Comment: That is a total different kettle of fish in a different kitchen...So what you want to do is send back the error response only.

Answer (score 0):

```html
**You should use**
codeigniter redirect in controller
redirect(url, 'refresh');
and 
use the form_error method to your view
<?php echo form_error('field name','<span class="help-block form-error">', '</span>'); ?>
```